# Интерфейсы (Java)

Tags: java, интерфейс, реализация

подскажите, пожалуйста. Как устроена реализация интерфейсов в java? К примеру, ActionListener. Мы создаем класс, имплиментим интерфейс и переопределяем абстрактный метод actionPerformed, где пишем код. Так вот, вопрос мой состоит в том, как устроена обработка события на уровне кода. Ведь, по логике, этой интерфейс должен содержать еще и неабстрактные методы, где, собственно, и будет заложена реализация, но их ведь нет.

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println ("Action!");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ведь, по логике, этой интерфейс должен содержать еще и неабстрактные
> методы, где, собственно, и будет заложена реализация, но их ведь нет. - *Интерфейс ничего не должен, должны все кто его реализуют.*

Если говорить простым языком интерфейс может содержат в себе протокол (методы которые нужно реализовать), а также статичные, абстрактные и дефолтные методы с реализыцией. Интерфейс это специальный указатель на объект экземпляр класса реализующий его.

Возращяясь к ActionListener.

```
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);

}
```

Класс реализующий данный интерфейс

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println ("Action!");
    }
    
}
```

имеет возможность передать указатель типа `ActionListener` другому объекту который вызовет `actionPerformed` метод. Сделано это для того, чтобы написать универсальный класс которому достаточно знать что есть `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное